# How to output just html image tag when I have text and html in django template output?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using this to output,

```
{{ movie.img }}
```

and I get the output is supposed to be something like,

```
u'<img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/8a/Dark_Knight.jpg/220px-Dark_Knight.jpg" alt="" height="327" width="220" >\nTheatrical release poster'
```

How do I just output the html image part? I don't want the Theatrical release poster to appear in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting that as just text, your best solution would be to write a template filter that would strip content not in the `<img>` html tag.

If the object were a ImageField (or FileField), you can call on the url attribute only, `{{ movie.img.url }}`

**update**

Ok, here's a basic, probably too naive template filter for your use.

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
import re

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
@stringfilter
def get_img_tag(value):
    result = re.search("<.*?>", value)
    if result:
        return result.group()
    return value
```

Use:

```
{{ movie.img|get_img_tag|safe }}
```

Comment: but that would be if url was separate, here I it's just plain text, which has html in it.

Comment: movie is a dictionary, in which one of the keys is u'img' and it maps to u'<img src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/8/8a/Dark_Knight.jpg/220px-Dark_Knight.jpg" alt="" height="327" width="220" >\nTheatrical release poster' I am not sure if it's an ImageField. How do I go about that?

Comment: how is Movie defined in your models.py?

Comment: there is no models.py The model part is handled by my teammate who is using a mongodb database and a call to his api returns a list of python dictionary, and each of these dictionaries is equivalent to movie

Comment: Oh. game changer. You could write a template filter to strip content not in the `<img>` tag

Comment: Okay, thanks :) This looks like a solution. Gotta learn how to write a template filter now!